# cut off last few characters of values passed with JavaScript split function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, split, webforms

I have Javascript code passing start and end timedate values from a previous page, however, the start value contains additional characters which are not needed. Is there a way in which I can shave off the unnecessary characters?

The URL of in the search bar when forwarded is `localhost:56363/Bookings.aspx#start=27/02/2018 12:30&end=27/02/2018 17:30`
and the `&end` is passed to the start input box but not needed. The JavaScript code is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    hash();
    function hash() {
      var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('#');
      for (var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++) {
        var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
        document.getElementById("<%=start.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
      }
      var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++) {
        var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
        document.getElementById("<%=end.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
      }
    }
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: You should `split ("&")` then iterate over that and take `[key, value] = entry.split("=")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash parameters?! What!

Most apps will use query parameters with a url that looks like `localhost:56363/Bookings.aspx?start=27/02/2018 12:30&end=27/02/2018 17:30` notice the `?` instead of a hash. Query parameters would be available as `window.location.search`

Anyway. Change your `hash()` function to

```
function hash(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    var start = hash.match(/start=([^&]+)/)[1];
    document.getElementById("<%=start.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(start);

    var end = hash.match(/end=([^&]+)/)[1];
    document.getElementById("<%=end.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(end);
}
```

The regular expressions will find the relevant parameters and the capture group `([^&]+)` will capture the value of each parameter. We then use the `[1]` to retrieve the value of each parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much, Works perfectly